# Javascript Trigger onChange without performing mouse or keyboard

Tags: javascript, events, select, triggers, onchange

Some function get call when i change item is "Select" tag.
I want to trigger onchange event using javascript code just like somebtn.click() can trigger click event.

```
<select id="abc">
<option selected>item1</option>
<option>item2</option>
<option>item3</option>
</select>
```

I want when page load or at any other event, item3 get selected automatically and onchange function automatically called as item3 is selected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

So... just do it:

```
function selectOption($select, option) {
    if ($select.val() != option) {
        $select.val(option).trigger('change');
    }
}

// Usage:
selectOption( $('#abc'), 'item3');
```